# Sum every X rows with no common group by parent

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Trying to sum every X rows with no common group by parent

```
declare @temp table(Row_ID int, amt DECIMAL(18,2))
insert into @temp values(1, 20)
insert into @temp values(2, 24)
insert into @temp values(3, 20)
insert into @temp values(4, 15)
insert into @temp values(5, 15)
```

If X rows is 2 then desired result is to sum ever 2 rows and place total next to the rows. So first 2 rows total to 44 , next 2 rows to 35 , 1 remaining so total  15

```
Row_ID  amt     tot
1       20.00    44.00
2       24.00    44.00
3       20.00    35.00
4       15.00    35.00
5       15.00    15.00
```

If X rows is 3 then desired result

```
Row_ID  amt     tot
1       20.00    64.00
2       24.00    64.00
3       20.00    64.00
4       15.00    30.00
5       15.00    30.00
```

If X rows is 1 then desired result

```
Row_ID  amt     tot
1       20.00    20.00
2       24.00    24.00
3       20.00    20.00
4       15.00    15.00
5       15.00    15.00
```

Comment: As they a batched by 2 rows 20 + 15 = 35

Comment: Example 2 is batched into 3 rows , so first 3 rows summed to 64 then only 2 left which are summed 30

Comment: example 1 is batched by 2 rows, 20 + 24 = 44 ,  20 + 15 = 35 and 5th row remaining so its just 15

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way is to divide the rows into groups/partitions - using simple math (integer division) and group `over` the partitions. I assume that the `Row_ID` values are `UNIQUE`.

If - unlikely but if - there are no gaps in the `Row_ID` values and they start from `1`, then we could use the simple:

```
select row_id, amt,
       sum = sum(amt) over (partition by (row_id-1)/@GroupSize)
from t ;
```

But since this is unlikely - the values probably come from an `IDENTITY` column or a `SEQUENCE`, which don't guarantee gapless sequences - we have to create a gapless sequence, with `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
with c as
  ( select row_id, amt,
           grp = (row_number() over (order by row_id) - 1) / @GroupSize
    from t
  )
select row_id, amt,
       sum = sum(amt) over (partition by grp)
from c ;
```

Tested in **[dbfiddle.uk](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=b57552ac0b552a6dc9c82c073561af77)**:

> ```
> create table t 
> (Row_ID int, amt DECIMAL(18,2)
> ) ;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into t values
>   (1, 20),
>   (2, 24),
>   (3, 20),
>   (4, 15),
>   (5, 15) ;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 5 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> with c as
>   ( select row_id, amt,
>            grp = (row_number() over (order by row_id) - 1) / 2
>     from t
>   )
> select row_id, amt,
>        sum = sum(amt) over (partition by grp)
> from c ;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> row_id | amt   | sum  
> -----: | :---- | :----
>      1 | 20.00 | 44.00
>      2 | 24.00 | 44.00
>      3 | 20.00 | 35.00
>      4 | 15.00 | 35.00
>      5 | 15.00 | 15.00
> ```

> ```
> with c as
>   ( select row_id, amt,
>            grp = (row_number() over (order by row_id) - 1) / 3
>     from t
>   )
> select row_id, amt,
>        sum = sum(amt) over (partition by grp)
> from c ;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> row_id | amt   | sum  
> -----: | :---- | :----
>      1 | 20.00 | 64.00
>      2 | 24.00 | 64.00
>      3 | 20.00 | 64.00
>      4 | 15.00 | 30.00
>      5 | 15.00 | 30.00
> ```

In order to make the number of rows parametrisable, you just need to replace the divisor in the `grp` expression with a parameter/variable reference:

```
grp = (row_number() over (order by row_id) - 1) / @GroupSize
```

and, consequently, pass the parameter value when you invoke the query.

Comment: great thankyou! - love the simple divide for the grouping i was close but just couldn't quite get it.

Comment: This is a long shot as the question is answered but would it be possible to not add the sum if there are enough rows, so row_id 4 & 5 would be 0

Comment: `sum2 = case when count(*) over (partition by grp) = @GroupSize then sum(amt) over (partition by grp) else 0 end`